# A group with a normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have to prove the following problem:

"Let $p,q$ positive prime numbers,p>q and $k$ a positive integer. Prove that if $G$ is group of order $p^kq$, then $G$ has a normal subgroup $H$ such that $\{e\}\not=H\not=G$."

I tried to prove that $1<|z(G)|<p^kq$ where $z(G)$ is the center of $G$ and so $z(G)$ would be my normal subgroup, but I couldn't do any real progress. Can you help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, there exist centerless groups with those orders, so that will be an issue! For example, the dihedral group of symmetries of a pentagon has order $2 \cdot 5$ and no center. Do you have Sylow theory at your disposal? (I don't know if it will be helpful, but I suspect so)

Comment: What is $\;H\;$ in your question?

Comment: Oh I didn't think about that  group. H is the subgroup i want to prove it exists and I don't have Sylow at my disposal only Cauchy.

Comment: I'm going to wait for this question's answer without Sylow theorems. I really can't think how to do it.

Comment: $G$ must have a subgroup $S$ of order $q$, which will have index $p^k$. Then there is an induced homomorphism $\psi:G\to S_{p^k}$ with $\ker\psi\le S$. But $S$ has prime order so $\ker\psi=1$ or $\ker\psi=S$. If $\ker\psi=S$ we are done. If $\ker\psi=1$, ... I'm not really sure where to go with it from here

Comment: Hmm, I see a way to do this if you can rule out a subgroup of order $q$ being self-normalizing (I happen to know that you will be able to find a normal subgroup of order $p^k$). But getting this without Sylow seems a bit tricky.

Answer (score 1):

The number $n_p$ of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ divides $q$ and satisfies $n_p\equiv_p1$. As $p>q$, $n_p=1$.

In particular, the unique Sylow $p$-subgroup $H$ is normal and has order $p^k$, so $\{e\}<H<G$.

Comment: The OP mentioned in a comment that they only know Cauchy, not Sylow.

Comment: Then one would need to prove Sylow theorems starting from Cauchy's theorem. The Sylow $q$-subgroup need not be normal .